# PHP Laravel Service & Action

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Во всех примерах которые я нашел по теме Action и Service, эти два класса будто-то бы взаимозаменяемы, параллельны. Если кода много выношу из контроллера в сервис, если кода на одно действие, выношу в Action.

Насколько корректно использовать controller->service->action (вызывать action внутри сервиса).
В сервисе у меня методы одной условной модели. Где-то пишут что это тоже не очень, но в целом выглядит достаточно удобно. Остается проблема что по одному условному роуту, выполняет логику один метод сервиса, но иногда в нем получается уж слишком много логики.